# Upload Tables In HANA

Tags: upload, teradata, hana

I am a HANA newbie, coming from a Teradata environment.
In Teradata, I can use Fastload to upload data and create tables.
Is there an equivalent in HANA?  I have only been able to find instructions that need to use HANA Studio, but I would like to do this on a command line.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

With SAP HANA on-board tools there are several options to get data into your DB:

- write `INSERT` statements: obvious, but probably not what you're after
- Import/Export via SAP HANA Studio: as you mentioned - that's GUI driven
- using [Smart Data Integration](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/27/hana-sp9-data-provisioning-overview/) (SDI): enables direct connections to/from many source system types and support real-time and batch data loading. Probably not what you would use for a once off data load
- using the SAP HANA development environment to create "transportable" code/data-packets that can be deployed on multiple databases: this is more suitable for demo- or configuration data

Last but not least:

- SQL commands [`IMPORT`/`EXPORT`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/20a5342e75191014bb95e83cbbe772fa.html): these commands offer **server-side** data import and export and are usually the quickest option to bulk-load a HANA database. This may be what you are looking for.
  The main **caveat**, however, is that the **data must be located in a filesystem that can be accessed by the HANA processes**.
  Since this is triggered via SQL commands, you can easily write scripts and run those scripts from any client e.g. *hdbsql* (the command line interface for HANA), *HANA Studio* or any other tool that allows runnings to run SQL commands with HANA.